# Reduce function works but takes too long, vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, reduce

In my Vue app, I have a reduce function that's being called within an html/vue loop and it's taking far too long; around 21 seconds

During that time, nothing renders and the page freezes temporarily

I think part of the issue is that I'm calling the computed property in a loop and it calls the reduce function each time, but I'm still unclear on a way to optimize this to quickly go through the reduce function and allow the loop to only hit the result set as opposed to reducing through each iteration.

My result set is about 12,000 records but I've only included a few in the exact structure.

What can I do here?

```js
<script>
const reduceFunction = (rows) =>
  rows .reduce(
    (a, row) => {
      const employee = a [row .employee] || (a [row .employee] = {dates: {}, total_categories:0, total_items: 0, area: '', group: ''})
      const date = employee .dates [row .itemDate] || (employee .dates [row .itemDate] = {categories: 0, qty: 0, total_categories: 0, unavailable: 0, orders: {}})

      date.categories += +row.categories_per_item * +row.qty
      date.qty += +row.qty

      date.total_categories = date.categories

      const order = date .orders [row .order_number] || (date .orders [row .order_number] = {itemDate: '', skus: {}})

      order.itemDate = row.itemDate;

      const sku = order .skus [row .sku] || (order .skus [row .sku] = {categories: '', qty: '', itemDate: '', expected: '', created: '', unavailable: 0, available:0})

      sku.categories += row.categories_per_item
      sku.qty += row.qty
      sku.itemDate = row.itemDate
      sku.expected = row.shipDate
      sku.created = row.created_date
      sku.heir_id = row.heir_identifier

      employee.total_categories += (+row.categories_per_item * +row.qty)
      employee.total_items += (+row.qty)
      employee.area = row.area
      employee.group = row.group_name
      employee.warehouse = row.warehouse 
      employee.locale = row.locale


      const foundKit = vm.$data.kitsData.find((kit) => kit.heir_identifier === sku.heir_id)

      if (foundKit) {

        new_avail = 10;

        if(sku.qty > new_avail){
          status.status = "Not available";
          date.unavailable += 1
          sku.unavailable += 1
        }else{
          status.status = "Available"
        }
      }else{
        status.status = "No item found"
      }

      return a
    },
    {}
  );


var vm = 
new Vue({
  el: "#app",

  data: {
    rows: [
            {  
                employee: "Adam",
                sku: "A1453",
                categories_per_item: "15",
                area: "1",
                itemDate: "2021-11-02",
                qty: 37,
                group_name: "managers",
                warehouse: "3",
                order_number: "1234",
                locale: "1",
                shipDate: "2020-02-02",
                created_date: "2020-01-01",
                heir_identifier:"ABC3"
            },
            {  
                employee: "Joan",
                sku: "A1453",
                categories_per_item: "15",
                area: "1a",
                itemDate: "2021-11-02",
                qty: 17,
                group_name: "managers",
                warehouse: "3",
                order_number: "34578",
                locale: "1",
                shipDate: "2020-02-02",
                created_date: "2020-01-01",
                heir_identifier:"ABC3"
            },
            {  
                employee: "Bill",
                sku: "A1453",
                categories_per_item: "15",
                area: "1",
                itemDate: "2021-11-03",
                qty: 57,
                group_name: "managers",
                warehouse: "3",
                order_number: "2345",
                locale: "1",
                shipDate: "2020-02-02",
                created_date: "2020-01-01",
                heir_identifier:"ABC3"
            },
            {  
                employee: "PJ",
                sku: "A6512",
                categories_per_item: "150",
                area: "2",
                itemDate: "2021-11-03",
                qty: 20,
                group_name: "managers",
                warehouse: "3",
                order_number: "34567",
                locale: "1",
                shipDate: "2020-02-02",
                created_date: "2020-01-01",
                heir_identifier:"ABC1"
            }
        ]
  },
  methods: {

  },

  computed: {
    employeeData() {
      console.log('employee data')
      employeeRows = reduceFunction(this.rows)
      return employeeRows
      console.log(employeeRows)
    },

    dates() {
      return Array.from(Array(11), (_, i) => new Date(Date.now() + i * 86400000).toISOString().slice(0,10))
    }
    
  }
});


</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<tr v-for="(value, employee) in employeeData"  :key="employee">
  <td>@{{employee}}</td>
  <td v-for="date in dates" :key="date" >
    <div v-for="(dateInfo, dateValue) in value.dates" :key="dateValue" >
      <div v-if="dateValue == date ">
       
        @{{ dateInfo.total_categories }}
      
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried to move the renderFunction to `methods:`?

Comment: you mean the ```reduceFunction```? I definitely could, if that would be more performant in any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach for this problem would be to invoke `reduceFunction` on `mounted(){}`
and create another state for the array, here I called it `parsedRows`
So basically to avoid unnecessary re rendering.

```js
 
data: {
  rows: []
  parsedRows: []

}
methods: {
  reduceFunction(data){
     //adjust your code to fit method here
  }
}
mounted(){
  this.parsedRows = this.reduceFunction(this.rows);
}
```

and then use the `parsedRows` on the Vue template.
Also to move the reduceFunction to `methods`

Answer (score 1):

The main improvement I could see would be to eliminate the nested loop here:

```
const foundKit = vm.$data.kitsData.find((kit) => kit.heir_identifier === sku.heir_id)
```

Organize the `kitsDat` by `heir_identifier` first so you can look up in `O(1)` instead of `.find`ing (`O(n)`) each time.

```
const kitsByHeir = new Map();
for (const kit of vm.$data.kitsData) {
  kitsByHeir.set(kit.heir_identifier, kit);
}
```

Then do `kitsByHeir.get(sku.heir_id)` inside the loop.

You might also use a `for` loop instead of `reduce` (`reduce` is arguably [not appropriate in this situation anyway](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaGjS7-qWzg))

Also, processing 12,000 records *on the client-side* is pretty odd. Even with the best designed code, that could take an uncomfortable amount of time in certain environments. Consider moving the processing to a server instead.

Comment: I think the question said it’s 21 seconds with only 4 records. Hence O(n) wouldn’t be so much difference than O(1)

Comment: He said it's 21 seconds with 12,000 records (and that only a few records are included in the question, simply to give an example of the data structure)

Comment: OPs issue, as he said, is probably related to mutating the value of rows inside of a computed property that is dependant on that value, which is then used in the rendered output; this will cause a horrible number of re-rendering cycles. It's easy to end up with infinite loops when modifying values inside of computed and watched properties.

Comment: I did a small test in the console and it seems with 12k rows you could save 2-3 seconds, which is significant! But, probably not the cause of OPs problem. Thinking about optimizing the theoretical worse-case time-complexity of a single nested loop sounds very nice though (being non-sarcastic here!), but I'm not sure it makes a huge difference in a lot of cases, especially in front-end JS when generally you're not dealing with a lot of records, and especially when you consider that the code you write generally goes through a transpiler and then further munged and optimized by the JS engine.

Comment: Not that that's what you were arguing for in general ^_^ just giving my 2 cents. I agree that 12k records is unusual to handle on the front-end. I'd expect those records to be processed on the backend before coming down the pipe.

Comment: Absolutely. I don’t think 12k records would result 21 seconds due to time complexity. When its O(n)

Comment: I definitely think I'm going to replace the main bit of that function with server-side processing instead, only leaving the bit that you modified above. Thanks!